# Launching an Activity based on a file in android

Tags: android, android-intent, mime-types

I am developing an application which lists files in a folder (in a ListView).  When the user clicks on one of the items, if it is a file, then I would like to launch an activity that can handle it, if any, or display some kind of error message if there is none.

How can I do that?  Not the whole thing, of course, but how can I determine which application(s) can handle a file, if any.

Comment: There are many other similar posts about this but nothing this specific and nothing that answers my question, so please carefully read the other posts before flagging this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 7):

First, you will need to determine the MIME type of the file. You can do this using [MimeTypeMap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/MimeTypeMap.html):

```
MimeTypeMap map = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
String extension = map.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url); // url is the url/location of your file
String type = map.getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
```

Then once you know the MIME type, you can create an intent for that type:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType(type);
```

Finally, you want to check if any activities can resolve the intent with that type. This can be done via the [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html):

```
PackageManager manager = getPackageManager(); // I'm assuming this is done from within an activity. This a Context method.
List<ResolveInfo> resolvers = manager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
if (resolvers.isEmpty()) {
  // display error
} else {
  // launch the intent. You will also want to set the data based on the uri of your file
}
```

Comment: I tried this, and it works fine with some extensions like 'pdf' and 'doc', but it gives me a long non-sense list when I use 'JPG'; it shows system tools such as GPS as an applcaition that can handle 'JPG'. ANy other suggestions?

Comment: There is also a getPreferredActivities() method in the PackageManager which you can leverage to determine if there is a preferred app of handling a specific MIME type but otherwise, that is the intended android behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Based on...

> how can I determine which application(s) can handle a file, if any?

I think what you want is [PackageManager.queryIntentActivities](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryIntentActivities%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) where you create an intent based on the target file and then read the returned list.